# ATG Commerce v11 CRS install Error:

Tags: atg, endeca, oracle-commerce

I have installed Oracle ATG v11 with the commerce reference store, when I startup the production server and go to the url domain/crs/storeus I see the blank white page, and have the following error in the console:

```
Oct 13, 2014 1:56:37 PM com.endeca.infront.site.SiteManager getSite
SEVERE: Unable to retrieve site definition for site id: /storeSiteUS
com.endeca.store.exceptions.PathNotFoundException: No node found at
path: [pages].
        at com.endeca.store.configuration.InternalNode.getNode(InternalNode.java:153)
        at com.endeca.store.configuration.InternalNode.getNodeInfo(InternalNode.java:221)
        at com.endeca.store.configuration.InternalNode.getNode(InternalNode.java:150)
        at com.endeca.store.configuration.InternalNode.getNode(InternalNode.java:61)
........................................
**** Error      Mon Oct 13 13:00:47 +00:00 2014 1413205247448   /atg/endeca/assembler/droplet/InvokeAssembler   A problem occurred
assembling the content for content item /content/Web/Home Pages. The
response received was {@type=ContentSlot,
atg:currentSiteProductionURL=/crs/storeus,
canonicalLink=com.endeca.infront.cartridge.model.NavigationAction@2b35e9c6,
ruleLimit=1, @error=com.endeca.infront.content.ContentException:
com.endeca.navigation.ENEConnectionException: Error establishing
connection to retrieve Navigation Engine request

http://localhost:15000/graph?node=0&profiles=sitegroup.siteGroupUS|NoPriceRange|site.storeSiteUS&offset=0&nbins=0&irversion=640'.

Tried all: '2' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server:
'localhost', port: '15000' Check MDEX Logs and specified query
parameters. , contentCollection=/content/Web/Home Pages}. Servicing
the error open parameter.
```

I am assuming this error is related to endeca? I have downloaded CAS, Tools And Frameworks with experience manager and MDX, and Platform Services. Do I need to start these or have I missed a part of the endeca install?

Comment: You have to start the services. Check that you have both "Endeca HTTP service" and "Endeca Tools Service" running.

Comment: I have run the following commands to start the services: source /oracle/atg/endeca/PlatformServices/workspace/setup/installer_sh.ini
source /oracle/atg/endeca/Workbench/workspace/setup/installer_sh.ini
source /oracle/atg/endeca/MDEX/6.5.1/mdex_setup_sh.ini

$ENDECA_ROOT/tools/server/bin/startup.sh   
$ENDECA_TOOLS_ROOT/server/bin/startup.sh

Comment: what does `ps -ef` tell you? Do you have your services running? What about `netstat -a | grep 15000`? Do you have anything listening on port `15000`? Is Endeca installed on the same box as ATG?

Answer (score 0):

The value of the configurationPath attribute in the DefaultFileStoreFactory.properties located at  \localconfig\atg\endeca\assembler\cartridge\manager  may be incorrect.

In OOTB CRS, we normally provide the following value for configurationPath  attribute : 
/ToolsAndFrameworks/11.1.0/server/workspace/state/repository/CRS

Could you please verify the .zip is present at path provided in DefaultFileStoreFactory.properties.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if you are able to connect the below url:

`host:15000/admin?op=stats`

If you are able to connect this URL, then MDEX is running. Also, you can login to the experience manager and check if the dgraphs and dgidx are running.

If you are not able to connect then check all the services are(tools and http) running and accessible. You can check the endeca logs to debug further.

Answer (score 0):

**Your DGraph is not (yet) started.** 
(Hit this URL in your browser and verify: `http://localhost:15000/graph?node=0&profiles=sitegroup.siteGroupUS|NoPriceRange|site.storeSiteUS&offset=0&nbins=0&irversion=640&format=xml`)

Possible reasons are:

1. You did not run *baseline update* from ATG (from
   `ProductCatalogSimpleIndexingAdmin` *dyn/admin* component).
2. You did not run *promote content* (from your Endeca App's control folder).
3. Your Services are not working properly (or not started at all).  Check that `Platform Services` and `Tools And Frameworks` are started.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to properly define the value for the property `configurationPath=E:/Endeca/Apps/CRS/data/workbench/application_export_archive/CRS` in `"DefaultFileStoreFactory.properties"`

If you are using the OS as Windows then define this path as Unix style as shown above.